# How to get folder structure of Content Builder using REST Api

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, c#, content-builder

Does anyone know how to retrieve the folder structure of Content Builder using **REST** Api? I have read the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/assetAdvancedQuery.htm) but there is no example or anything that can point me to the right direction.

I have tried to set:

```
query.property = "ContentType";
query.simpleOperator = "in";
query.value = new string[] { "folder" };
fields = new string[] { "Name", "ID" };
```

But the response does not return any item. Can anyone shade some light on this please?
Thanks in advance,
Arman G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that in Content Builder, instead of data folders they are called categories. Check [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/176274/how-to-get-content-builder-categories-with-rest-api-call) for how to retrieve a list of categories.

Answer (score 0):

This might be of help - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/datafolder.htm - I think it would be helpful if SFMC documentation would do some cross-linking on this topic.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I saw that but it is for SOAP requests, I am using REST.